# Finding line numbers for string

Tags: powershell

I have a text file,

```
1=564
698=697
54=445
4=697
664=45
4=697
```

Notice how I have two occurrences of `4=697`

```
$INI = '\\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\CalenderGroup\config.ini'
$Read_INI = Get-Content $INI

$find = $Read_INI | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch "^\d+=697$"}

foreach($i in $find)
{    
    $Read_INI | Select-String -AllMatches "$i" -SimpleMatch
}
```

The above script looks up numbers ending with =697, this is partially working.

This is what I'm getting, it thinks I have 4 instances of 4=697 when I only have 2

```
698=697
4=697
4=697
4=697
4=697
```

This is what I want to get

```
698=697
4=697
4=697
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point `Select-String` directly to the file if you want the line numbers:

```
$INI = '\\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\CalenderGroup\config.ini'
Select-String -Path $INI -Pattern "^\d+=697$" |Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
```

---

What happens in your example is that:

```
$INI = '\\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\CalenderGroup\config.ini'
$Read_INI = Get-Content $INI

$find = $Read_INI | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch "^\d+=697$"}
```

stores the strings `698=697`, `4=697` and `4=697` in `$find`.

First time the `foreach` loop runs, `$i` is `698=697`, and `Select-String` finds that line once in `$Read_INI`.

Second time the `foreach` loop runs, `$i` is `4=697`, and `Select-String` finds that line *twice* in `$Read_INI`.

Third run is a repetition of the second run, so both values are output twice

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\config.ini" | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "=" | where P2 -EQ 697
```